# Azure Website Cannot register TypeScriptBuildConfigurations via Kudu

Tags: asp.net, azure, kudu

For my ASP.NET website, I am using typescript/react/jsx stack for client side development. For my local my build is fine and project is running.

But when I try to deploy on Azure via Continuous Deployment process, build does not recognize jsx files and throws error.

[image]

I fixed this error on my local by following this blog:
[Working around "Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided." using the TypeScript 1.6 beta](http://www.cyotek.com/blog/working-around-cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided-using-the-typescript-1-6-beta?published=False)

I wanted to apply same changes on Azure website but I am getting access denied error on this.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

[image]

Comment: I don't know the specifics of what you are doing, but generally, you cannot write to any top level location like Program Files.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I am trying to deploy my asp.net web app to Azure. Build on Azure throws error related to jsx files. Did you check the blog post I mentioned? How can I fix that issue?